# SQL Server: Change the value text on queried results

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to return and change all entries in column `login` for each entry that the value  = "Change this text" to "Requester". The below works but is only returns 2 values, "User" and "Requester" although there are 7 other entries where `login` = "Change this text"

```
declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='Hospital1';

SELECT CASE login

        WHEN 'Change this text' THEN 'Requester'
        ELSE 'User'
       END    

FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
GROUP BY MainHospital, login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by MainHospital & Login, so per hospital you only handle 2 cases. By grouping all of the results together, you are removing duplicate rows.

If you remove the grouping and it will return 7 rows:

```
SELECT CASE login
    WHEN 'Change this text' THEN 'Requester'
    ELSE 'User'
   END    
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
```

Otherwise include another unique column that will prevent the grouping.